# How to batch covert a folder of mp4 files to avi?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, avi

I'm trying to batch convert a folder of MP4 files to AVI using this script:

`for f in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -q:v 6 "encoded/${f%.*}.avi”; done`

(This is based an earlier question that was helpfully answered for me by @Mulvya here: [What's the best way to convert mp4 to avi?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/20399/whats-the-best-way-to-convert-mp4-to-avi))
I'm receiving the error message:

`Unable to find a suitable output format for 'encoded/test file.avi”; done
for f in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i test'
encoded/test file.avi”; done
for f in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i test: Invalid argument`

Can anyone suggest where i may have made a mistake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the `”` to a `"`.

Avoid using TextEdit or other "smart" editors to edit your scripts and shell commands. They will mangle it with fancy quotes and other oddball characters and ruin your commands.